# Unexpected token error when combining two valid json object

Tags: javascript, python, json

I am doing a web application which needs to load a JSON file from the server, when I try to parse that file I encountered the `Unexpected Token` error. I then find out the problem happens when two items appear in one file

Here is the two JSON items:

```
{
    "黄南":{"id":10973,"name":"黄南","prov":"青海","latt":35.519549,"logi":102.015248}, 
    "海北":{"id":10970,"name":"海北","prov":"青海","latt":36.954413,"logi":100.900998}
}
```

I have tried `JSON.parse` in chrome console, `json.loads` in python and [JSONlint.com](http://jsonlint.com), they all raise errors.

The interesting part is that when I tried to load them individually, there was no error, but as long as they are loaded together, the error is thrown out

So can anyone tell me what is happening and how to avoid this?
Thank you guys and sorry if there is any gramma issues in my description.

Comment: I just copy pasted that in to jsonlint and it came back valid.

Comment: Where is the comma separating the two items?

Comment: works fine for me both as JSON and as a literal

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting from json.loads, and what version of python are you using? . It works fine for me in 3.4 with no parameters at all.  2.7 throws an ascii error, but that's not surprising since its not ascii characters, and 2.7 uses ascii by default.

Answer (score 0):

It's a guess without more info, but I'm guessing python 2.x without setting the encoding, because other than that there is no other reason.

Tried the most basic operations available in 3.4 and 2.7.  It works without issue in 3.4.  In 2.7, you need to use utf-8 or you'd get an error.

this will work with python 3.x but fail in 2.x

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4
import json
j = """{
    "黄南":{"id":10973,"name":"黄南","prov":"青海","latt":35.519549,"logi":102.015248},
    "海北":{"id":10970,"name":"海北","prov":"青海","latt":36.954413,"logi":100.900998}
}"""

o = json.loads(j)
print(json.dumps(o,indent=1))
```

This will work in 2.7, probably 2.6 too

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
j = """{
    "黄南":{"id":10973,"name":"黄南","prov":"青海","latt":35.519549,"logi":102.015248},
    "海北":{"id":10970,"name":"海北","prov":"青海","latt":36.954413,"logi":100.900998}
}"""

o = json.loads(j)
print(json.dumps(o,indent=1))
```